# Vagrant chef-client provisioning fails with Network Error

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I am trying to provision a VM using Vagrant and chef-client, but I'm getting an error when it hits the chef-client provisioning block. My Chef Server is setup on my local network.

My VagrantFile looks like this:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_client do |chef|
  chef.chef_server_url =  "https://api.mychefserver.domain.com/organizations/org1"
  chef.validation_client_name = "org1-validator"
  chef.validation_key_path = "./chef-repo/.chef/org1-validator.pem"
  chef.add_recipe "my_recipe"
  chef.delete_node = true
  chef.delete_client = true
end
```

The output from vagrant/chef-client is giving me this error:

```
[2014-03-04T11:10:22-06:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.10.4 ***
[2014-03-04T11:10:22-06:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 16217
Creating a new client identity for vagrant-poc1.domain.com using the validator key.
[2014-03-04T11:10:22-06:00] INFO: Client key /etc/chef/client.pem is not present - registering

================================================================================
Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "vagrant-poc1.domain.com"
================================================================================


Network Error:
--------------
There was a network error connecting to the Chef Server:
Error connecting to https://api.mychefserver.domain.com/organizations/org1/clients - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known



Relevant Config Settings:
-------------------------
chef_server_url  "https://api.mychefserver.domain.com/organizations/org1"

If your chef_server_url is correct, your network could be down.



[2014-03-04T11:10:22-06:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing the issue.  My best guess is I'm using the incorrect url for my chef server, but I can't seem to find anything that tells me what the correct format would be.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  The correct url was https://mychefserver.domain.com/organizations/org1.

Found it in my knife.rb file.

Comment: URL is different when using private chef. Organisations are not supported in Open source chef.